# C# Linq Entity Framework - Update database by modifying Excel cell value

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, entity-framework, vsto

I'm trying to write a program where the user can retrieve data from the database, change it and update it. 
My code to get data from the database (SQL Server) using Entity Framework is below:

```
using (context = new ClientModel())
        {
            var query =
                from c in context.ClientInfo
                select c;

            int i = 1;
            foreach (var c in query)
            {
                ws.Cells[i, 1].Value = c.Name;
                ws.Cells[i, 2].Value = c.LastName;
                ws.Cells[i, 4].Value = c.City;
                ws.Cells[i, 5].Value = c.Country;

                i++;
            }
        }
```

And the output is something like this:

[image]

However, I hit the brick wall when trying to update the database according to the cell value changes. How could I update my database if the user decides to change for instance "country2" to "country999"?

The solution I've found was to update the entire table that the user retrieved from the database. Below is the code:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (context = new ClientModel())
        {
            int i = 1;
            do
            {
                var tableClient = context.Client.Find(i);

                ws.Cells[i, 1].Value = tableClient.Name;
                ws.Cells[i, 2].Value = tableClient.LastName;
                ws.Cells[i, 3].Value = tableClient.City
                ws.Cells[i, 4].Value = tableClient.Coutry

                context.SaveChanges();
                i++;
            } while (ws.Cells[i, 1].Value == null);
        }
    }
```

However, the above code is not updating the database.

Comment: In addition to Caldazar's answer you might need to tell EF about the changes you've made for it to save them with `context.Entry(tableClient).State = EntityState.Modified;` just before `SaveChanges()`

Comment: No, I don't. However, after changing the code according to what Caldazar said, it hits now.

Answer (score 2):

You should switch `ws.Cells` and `tableClient`. What you're doing is populating Excel again, instead of other way around:

```
tableClient.Name = ws.Cells[i, 1].Value;
tableClient.LastName = ws.Cells[i, 2].Value;
tableClient.City = ws.Cells[i, 3].Value;
tableClient.Coutry = ws.Cells[i, 4].Value;
```

And you should also change your `while` condition probably, to look for `ws.Cells[i, 1].Value!=null`

Comment: it worked. Also I had to modfify the "var tableClient = context.Client.Find(i);", I was assuming that the usar would always the get the data with the primary key: 1,2,3,4.... Now it's working the code.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Would appreciate if you mark as answer :)